# Values returning as NaN after nesting

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm having trouble nesting my data. I get my count as NaN when i do the following:

```
  var sumstat = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {; return d.region;})
.key(function(d) {return +d.year})
.rollup(function(d) {return d.count;})
.entries(data);
```

This is the output I get on my console:

[image]

I'm not sure how I can capture the count. Any help please?

Comment: Is that `;` in the first key function causing an issue?

Comment: @DrewReese No, it's basically an [emtpy statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty) which looks unusual yet causes no harm.

Comment: Note, that the function provided to `.rollup()` gets passed the **array** of leaf elements, not an individual element. Since there is no `.count` property on type `Array` you get the `undefined`values. To get further help, please share at least an excerpt of your data.

Comment: To play around with nests you might want to ask [Mister Nester](https://bl.ocks.org/shancarter/raw/4748131/) which greatly helps prototyping a viable solution.